# How to use Date = value in google data studio calculated field?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to create the following calculated field:

```
CASE 
 WHEN Date = TODATE("Dec 1, 2020","%b %d, %Y","%b %d, %Y")
 THEN Steps Count
 ELSE 0
END
```

in order to get the number of steps as per December 1st.
It throws me an error that the formula is not valid, please advise what I am missing and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

what is the type of `Date` column? `TODATE` is used only for [compatibility mode dates](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300?hl=en). Maybe you need [PARSE_DATE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739156?hl=en&ref_topic=7583292) instead?

```
PARSE_DATETIME("%d/%m/%Y", "01/01/2020")
```